# Why doesn't my form validation work in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to have user validation in my django social media/blog app. I do not understand why this code does not work. The problem: No matter what name I type in the form it says the user does not exist even though the user does in fact exist. Any help would be amazing.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from sign_in.forms import SignInForm 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = User.objects.filter(username=username, password=password)
            if user.exists():
                return HttpResponseRedirect("boom/")
            else:
                messages.error(request, f"User {user} does not exist.")
    else:
        form = SignInForm()

    return render(request, "sign_in/sign_in.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not how Django authentication works.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/

use **authenticate** method

try this

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            if user.exists():
                return HttpResponseRedirect("boom/")
            else:
                messages.error(request, f"User {user} does not exist.")
    else:
        form = SignInForm()

    return render(request, "sign_in/sign_in.html", {"form": form})
```